# Partial differentiation problem

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I have a question that from a past exam(2007S2, UQ, MATH1052), that is as follows:
"Let $w = f(x,y)$ and $x = rcos(\theta), y = rsin(\theta)$

Show that $\frac{dw}{dx}=\frac{dw}{dr}*cos(\theta) - \frac{dw}{d\theta}*\frac{sin(\theta)}{r}$
and $\frac{dw}{dy}=\frac{dw}{dr}*sin(\theta) + \frac{dw}{d\theta}*\frac{cos(\theta)}{r}$

Now I am not sure what I am not understanding on this one... It looks like $f(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))$, meaning I would just derive w with respect to x and y to show that the above is true, however, I don't know w, and integrating the above seems like a ridiculous way to solve the problem(integrate it and derive it...)

The way they are treating it makes me think the problem should look more like: $f(r(x,y),\theta(x,y))$, which gives us the solutions:
$$ \frac{dw}{dx}=\frac{dw}{dr}*\frac{dr}{dx} + \frac{dw}{d\theta}*\frac{d\theta}{dx}$$
and
$$ \frac{dw}{dy}=\frac{dw}{dr}*\frac{dr}{dy} + \frac{dw}{d\theta}*\frac{d\theta}{dy}$$

But working out $\frac{dr}{dx}$, we have $r = \frac{x}{cos(\theta)}$, so $\frac{dr}{dx}$ $=  \frac{1}{cos(\theta)}$ and therefore not $cos(\theta)$

Am I just doing something dumb, or thinking about this wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We have $r = \dfrac{x}{\cos\theta} \implies \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \dfrac{1}{\cos\theta}$

There are two partial derivatives here: $\left(\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)_{\theta}$ and $\left(\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)_y$ - the subscript on the partial derivative indicates which variable you should hold constant. You have derived the former but, conventionally with plane polar coordinates, $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ signifies the latter.

To proceed, write $r=r(x,y)$.

Hint: $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

Comment: When doing partial derivatives, don't we normally hold everything bar the 'with respect to' as constant? $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ all but x are constant?

Also one further question, what exactly does this function look like? $w = f(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))$ or $w = f(r(x,y),\theta(x,y))$ or other?

Comment: Never-mind, I now understand. Thank you Cody!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$r^2=x^2+y^2
\\2r\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=2x=2r\cos\theta$$
You should use $\partial$ instead of $d$ in many places in your Q. Also $\cos \theta$ cotains $x$ so your last partial derivative is wrong